# Pass data from $_POST to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to send a input data (code_bar ) at return.php page, which after a MySQL select callback 3 data ( prezzo;prodotto;descrizione ) but it doesn't work. I post here html file with JavaScript and PHP file which calls a data from select to my db.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="">
Codice a Barre <p>
<input id="code_bar" name"code_bar" />
<button onclick="button">Chiama</button><p>
Prodotto<p>
<input id="Prodotto" name="Prodotto" /><p>
Prezzo<p>
<input id="Prezzo" name="Prezzo"  /><p>
Descrizione <p>
<input id="Descrizione" name="Descrizione"  /
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function invia(){
    var code_bar = $("input#code_bar").val();
     $.ajax({
      url:"return.php", 
      data: {code_bar: 'code_bar'},
      success:function(data) {
            $("#Prezzo").val(data.Prezzo);
            $("#Prodotto").val(data.Prodotto);
            $("#Descrizione").val(data.Descrizione);
           
        
       "json"}
     });
}
</script>
```

**return.php**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['code_bar'])){
      $code_bar = $_POST['code_bar'];
   }
mysql_select_db($database_mydb, $mydb);
$query_estraggo = "SELECT * FROM prodotti WHERE code_bar = '$code_bar'";
$estraggo = mysql_query($query_estraggo, $mydb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_estraggo = mysql_fetch_assoc($estraggo);
$totalRows_estraggo = mysql_num_rows($estraggo);

      if ($row_estraggo = mysql_fetch_assoc($estraggo)){
          $ritorno = '{"Prezzo":'.$row_estraggo['Prezzo'].',"Prodotto":'.$row_estraggo['Prodotto'].',"Descrizione":'.$row_estraggo['Descrizione'].'}';
        

         $json = $JSON->encode($ritorno);
         echo $json;
         exit($ritorno);
          
      }
mysql_free_result($estraggo);
?>
```

Comment: SQL injection possible in `return.php`...

Answer (score 3):

you're passing in `GET` a string instead of the actual value

```
data: {code_bar: 'code_bar'},
```

write instead

```
data: {code_bar: code_bar},
```

anyway you should at least be able to understand where your call is failing (in you ajax call or in the server side script): e.g. Firebug has a `xhr` panel in which you can clearly see how data is passed

As a sidenote, in your `php` you should avoid all `mysql_*` function in favour of `PDO` statements

Comment: have you also changed `$.ajax` with `$.post`(as correctly suggested by xdazz)?

Comment: sorry but i don't have more experience with php/jascrcipt

Comment: you've got an extra `"json"` at the end of your success function... remove it. P.s: please, *"don't work"* doesn't mean nothing. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Ok sorry, If i try a pass manually a code_bar I receive a annswer but if i try to pass from form dont get data back

Comment: If try to send a test.php for echo $_POST I see only Array....more probably I cant send value to return.php

Comment: another typo: you wrote `name"code_bar"`  instead of `name="code_bar"`

Comment: Ok now my url change in ?code_bar=3&Prodotto=&Prezzo=&Descrizione=

Comment: but i cant receive data from return.php

Comment: Calderan non si può fare più nulla?

Answer (score 1):

The default type of request by `$.ajax` is `GET`, you need to set it to `POST`, or use `$.post` instead. (Your `$.ajax` has syntax error).

And `data: {code_bar: 'code_bar'},` will cause `code_bar` always be string `code_bar`, it should be `data: {code_bar: code_bar},`.

Comment: Ok i changed but dont work, I insert type in my button field but nothing change

Comment: After all change, now my url after submit change in ?Prodotto=&Prezzo=&Descrizione=

Answer (score -1):

```
        You should also define type of input
        <input id="code_bar" name"code_bar" type="text"/>
    In $.ajax default type is get if you send data with post method then add type:"post" in $.ajax method

    $.ajax({
          url:"return.php", 
          type:"post",
          data: {code_bar: code_bar},
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data) {
                $("#Prezzo").val(data.Prezzo);
                $("#Prodotto").val(data.Prodotto);
                $("#Descrizione").val(data.Descrizione);


           }
         });
```

Comment: The default `input` type is `text`, so that shouldn't matter.